# What is the difference between "ps -eu" and "ps -u"?

Tags: ps

I check the manual of `ps`, and it said `-e` will list all processes, while `-u` will list processes for a specific user.

So I try to use `ps -eu myaccount | wc -l` and it outputs 280.

But if I use `ps -u myaccount | wc -l` and it outputs 12.

Since both are used to output all the processes for the user `myaccount`, why the result will be different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A better question would be "What's the difference between `ps -e` and `ps -eu`" and the answer would be "nothing".

The `-e` option shows all processes, and basically replaces the `-u` selection.

As pointed out by @fra-san, the man page indicates all process selection options are additive.  The `-u` option selects, not filters, and you can't add any more processes after `-e` as they are already all there.

Comment: It is also worth to note that on a multiprocess system, which Unix-like systems are, the number of processes might differ between two invocations of `ps`. Also the header line will be counted by `wc`.